# Good iOS Table View Shadows (Like clock app)

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, shadow

I'm quite new to iOS coding and I can't seem to find a good tutorial version that tells me how to efficiently add shadows to table view.

I've tried  (then some other random ones): 
http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/08/adding-shadow-effects-to-uitableview.html 
Didn't work for me at all, gave me errors.

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/5939-safari-like-uiwebview-uiscrollview-uitableview-beyond-bounds-gradient.html
Tried the core graphics one that worked perfectly but is very slow on the iPhone. It's just not snappy. I also tried images but it just looked bad.

Is there a good version that is snappy like in the default clock app? There has to be some "standard."

Answer (score 0):

There’s no real standard, but CAGradientLayer is the right approach in most cases. What errors were you encountering with it?

Comment: I actually just fixed it, my CoreGraphics framework appeared in Files & Folders, but wasn't in project Build Phases for some reason. However, now the shadow doesn't appear. I'm confused how to exactly call the ShadowViewTable.h class that overwrites layoutSubviews is called/works. I tried calling the class (lol) in my first viewWillAppear but that unsurprisingly didn't work.

Comment: NVM. Got the "cocoawithlove" shadows working. I had to make sure that the object of my table view was the ShadowViewTable class.

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in Recipe 20, "Add Border Shadows for Table Views," of the iOS Recipes book by Matt Drance and Paul Warren.  The recipe adds shadow image views to a UITableView subclass which are repositioned as necessary in `layoutSubviews`.

I have also accomplished this using shadow image views as table header and footer properties, but this has the obvious downside of preventing you from adding other views as header and footer views.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the table header and footer in your table view, here is a very simple solution:

1. Add two gradient views (either images or subclasses of UIView with some gradient drawing) as tableHeaderView and tableFooterView. Can be done in Interface Builder.
2. Set content inset of the table view for top & bottom to the negative height of the gradient views.

You can find code samples for this solution here: http://rowboatrevolution.com/2009/06/drop-shadows-in-uitableview/

Answer (score 0):

I was just able to get an inner shadow on a table view via a little trick.

I put a 1px X 320px UIView at the top of the table view and then put a shadow around this view like this:

```
self.shadowWrapper.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
self.shadowWrapper.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
self.shadowWrapper.layer.shadowOpacity = .90f;
self.shadowWrapper.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0f;
```

In my case I had my table view half way down the page, so I used another view to sit above my "shadow wrapper" and hide the shadow on the top side of my shadow. This left a shadow sitting over the top of my table view giving the appearance of an inner shadow.